# how to delete item from list using delete button in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I am generating a dynamic list using `add button` .I am able to generate the dynamic list .But there is `delete` button  also present in each `li`.I want to delete the item when delete button is pressed .I make a `action` as well redux.Firstly I don''t know how to bind click event on dynamic generated list.I am getting error when user press delete button

here is my code
https://plnkr.co/edit/JEG6o4JCBIQWAt2A4S3r?p=preview
// Code goes here

```
const { createStore, bindActionCreators, applyMiddleware,combineReducers } = Redux;
const { Provider, connect } = ReactRedux;
const thunk = window.ReduxThunk.default;


const first_redux =function(state =[] ,action){
  switch (action.type){
    case 'ADD_ITEM':
     return [
        ...state,
        action.payload
      ];
      case 'DELETE_ITEM':
      var index = state.indexOf(action.payload);
     return state.slice(index,1);
    default :
    return state

  }
}

const actions ={
 addItem :function(item){
  return {
    type :"ADD_ITEM",
    payload :item
  } 
 } ,
 deleteItem :function(item){
  return {
    type :"DELETE_ITEM",
    payload :item
  } 
 } 

}
var combindReducer = combineReducers({
  item:first_redux
})

const store = createStore(combindReducer);

class First extends React.Component {
  constructor (props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      names :[],
      username :''
    }
   this.changeEv =this.changeEv.bind(this);
   this.addName =this.addName.bind(this);
   this.handle =this.handle.bind(this);

  }
  changeEv(e){
    this.setState({
      username : e.target.value
    })
  }
  addName(){
    if(this.state.username !== ''){
    this.props.add(this.state.username)
     this.setState({
      username : ''
    })
    }
  }
  handle(){
    alert('---')
  }

  render() {
    const data =[{"name":"test1"},{"name":"test2"}];
    var listItems = this.props.names.map(function(d, idx){
      return (<li key={idx}><span>{d}</span><button onClick={this.handle}>delete</button></li>)
    })
    return (
      <div>
      <input type="text" onChange ={this.changeEv} value={this.state.username}/>
      <button onClick={this.addName}>add</button>
      {listItems}
      </div>
    );
  }
} 

function mapStateToProps(state){
  console.log('=================');
  console.log(state);
  return {
       names: state.item,

  };
    console.log(this.state);

}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return {
    add:bindActionCreators(actions.addItem,dispatch)
  }
}
const Appcontainer =connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(First)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store ={store}>
    <Appcontainer/>
    </Provider>
  ,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: The plunkur is not working. When I hit add, I dont see a list getting generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Problem:**

You get an error in the delete button because the **this** you are trying to access inside the **this.props.names.map** is not the component's this.

**Solution**:

```
var listItems = this.props.names.map((d, idx) => {
  return (<li key={idx}><span>{d}</span><button onClick={this.handle}>delete</button></li>)
})
```

Since you are using ES6, you can use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which provide lexical scoping. I have updated your code. Check it out [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/NPghOK4FmC4RSBiP9oEE?p=preview)

Comment: so how to delete element ?

Comment: I have updated the plunkur with delete functionality. Just provide the delete action as prop to the component inside mapDispatchToProps (just like you did for adding an element).